# Using JsZip to create zip file programmatically

Tags: javascript, jszip

I wanna insert files pdf inside of the zip on loop and after download the file zip.

The problem is when I try to download the file thats came empty.
If I printer on console a variable zip, it's have my files..

```js
var zip = new JSZip();
var nomeCliente = "";
this.state.docs.forEach(function(itemDoc, index) {
  var file = new File([this.dataURItoBlob(response.data)], itemComment.comment_file_name, {type: response.mime+"charset=utf-8"});
      zip.folder(itemDoc.person_firstname).folder(itemDoc.category_description).file(itemComment.comment_file_name, file);
}
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
 .then(function(content) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(content, nomeCliente+".zip");
});
```

Comment: you need to generate() after you add the files and folders, and they are all done.

Comment: I've done like this before. See [here](https://jsgao0.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/zip-files-using-jszip/).

Comment: Do you have an empty file (0 byte) or an empty zip file (22 bytes) ? Could add a `console.log(zip.files)` before the call to `generateAsync` ? Also a `console.log(content.size)` before the call to `saveAs`.

Comment: An empty zip file @DavidDuponchel....

Comment: @dandavis , I did that.. take a look on code, my first loop is to populate the zip file, on my generate()  if I print the content on console is empty.

Comment: An empty zip file @DavidDuponchel....Exactly 22 bytes.. the content is empty, but the zip.files not.

Comment: @JoãoVitor: that should not happen. I tried to reproduce it (https://jsbin.com/piyezojure/edit) but I get a correct zip file. Could you use your values and see if you can reproduce the issue ? (and give us the jsbin showing the error)

Comment: @DavidDuponchel check the video. https://youtu.be/vdT1XlsnJyM

Comment: you call generate before the files are async added. flow control != timing control on async processes. the fact that your later console check (after allowing enough time to add() them) works proves that the line just below the forEach is running too soon. you should use events or monitoring, but i'd be willing to bet a short setTimeout wrap on the generate() would fix your issue 9/10 times as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in the video you posted in the comments, your code can be summarized as:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
docs.forEach(function () {                    // 1
  requestComments().end(function () {
    requestCommentFile().end(function () {
      zip.folder(...).folder(...).file(...);  // 2
    })
  });
  triggerDownload(zip);                       // 3
});
```

HTTP requests are asynchronous: `requestComments` and `requestCommentFile` will take time to complete and you need to wait for them before calling `triggerDownload`. Here, the execution order is 1, 3, 2: you prepare the HTTP requests, trigger the download (with an empty zip file) and *then* HTTP requests end and fill in the `zip` object.

To fix that, you must wait for the completion of all requests before calling `saveAs`.

JSZip accepts promises as content but here each request can lead to multiple zip entries so you can't use it. Instead, use promises and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Which ajax library do you use ? If the result is compatible with ES6 Promises, you can convert your code:

```
// from
comments.forEach(function () {
  request.post(...)
  .send(...)
  .end(function() {
    zip.file(...);
  });
});

// to
var commentsP = comments.map(function () { // forEach to map
  return request.post(...)                 // return here
  .send(...)
  .then(function() {                       // each time you see a then
    return zip.file(...);                  // ends with a return
  });
});
return Promise.all(commentsP);
```

In this example, `commentsP` is a list of promises and `Promise.all` will transform it into a promise of the list of results. That means once it resolves, *all* included promises have resolved.

Do that for all ajax requests (don't forget any `return`, it allow inner promises to be chained). In the end, wait for the top level promise before calling `triggerDownload` (`baixarZip` in your video).